# Locations of tears in Bioshock Infinite?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Okay, so I've got pretty well through Bioshock Infinite. After defeating

> the ghost of Elizabeth's mother,

I have to find three tears. I found the first one in the house with the infusion, but I can't seem to find the other two.

Where are they?

Comment: Walk around and look at your feet. You should notice some blue footsteps forming; those belong to the ghost and lead you to the other tears.

Comment: @Nolonar you could also press <kbd>N</kbd> (or whatever you changed it to) to display a hint arrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the tears (one each) in the Lutece Labs, in the Bank of the Prophet and in the Photo Studio.

You can find more information here (be aware of SPOILERS) : http://guides.gamepressure.com/bioshockinfinite/guide.asp?ID=19196